# How can I debug an error thrown from the minified version of the Google Picker API?

Tags: google-chrome, google-drive-api, google-api-js-client, google-picker

I'm attempting to use the `Google Picker` API from `Gapi` in a web application. Unfortunately, I believe there is a conflict between the `Google Picker` API and `Okta`. But, I can't really be sure because the error being thrown looks like this:

```
m=opnc:1067 Uncaught Error: xb
    at m=opnc:1067
    at e.O (m=opnc:409)
    at Cfa (m=opnc:412)
    at yfa (m=opnc:412)
    at _.vk.jy (m=opnc:412)
    at ofa (m=opnc:403)
```

How do I decipher this?